# Liferay: Hiding the Login Portlet for logged in users

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'd like to to hide the in-built "Sign-in" portlet for users that have logged in.

[image: Screenshot of config window]

How do I set permissions to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Liferay uses RBAC permission model, which probably won't allow you to achieve this through permissions. This is because it's utterly illogical to deprave a system role from a permission granted to a guest.

Consider some other options, from the top of my head:

- Create a layout-template which show or hides some portlet column depending on whether current user is not guest (not entirely sure if this will be that easy as it depends on which variables exactly are available in layout-template velocity environment)
- Wrap sign-in portlet in another portlet
- Simply hook *sign-in portlet*'s JSP
- Javascript maybe? Probably the easiest solution, not the best though

Comment: The suggestion about creating a layout template would be the way to go. Checkout this blog post for available velocity variables: http://alimozzaman.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/liferay-6-theme-variables/

Comment: Thanks Jonny, just the blog post I was thinking about!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving this is to create a public page which contains the Login portlet, let's say the page is called Login (this page and it's portlet should be viewable by guests).

Next, create another page and call this Welcome. Put some portlets on it for logged in users to see. The page should preferably private, however if it's public ensure you change permissions so guests can't see portlets etc..

Now go to Control Panel > Portal > Portal Settings and modify the Navigation links (hover over the question mark icon for informative tooltips explaining what each link does).

Here is an example, following on from what I've mentioned above with the Login and Welcome pages:

[image]

Simples! No code modifications or custom themes!

Answer (score 0):

Liferay adds the signed-in class to your `<body>` element. If you can live with it being available in HTML, but just not shown, add

```
.signed-in .portlet_login {
    display:none;
}
```

or similar to your theme or the login-portlet's look&feel advanced styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can render/not render many things based on `$is_signed_in` check in `Theme VM files`.

`is_signed_in` will be `true` for logged in users and `false` otherwise.

Some examples are below from `portal_vm.vm`

```
#if(!$is_signed_in)
            <a href="$sign_in_url" id="sign-in" rel="nofollow">$sign_in_text</a>             
#end


#if($is_signed_in)
#if($permissionChecker.isOmniadmin()== true)
    #dockbar()
#end

#if(!$is_signed_in)
                $theme.include($themeServletContext, "/jsp/someJsp.jsp")
 #end
```